# Are Old Slavonic verb рещи (reshchi) "to say, to command" cognates with PIE: [h₃reǵ]?

Tags: etymology

Can anybody please explain to me why the Old Slavonic verb рещи (reshchi) "to say, to command" does not reflect PIE: [h₃reǵ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%83re%C7%B5-) (related Terms: нарещи (nareshchi), изрещи (izreshchi), пророк (prorok), прорицати (proritsati), нарицати (naritsati), отърицатисѧ (otritsatisya), отърещисѧ (otreshchisya), предърицати (predritsati))?
, where
на/na, из/iz, про/pro, отъ/ot, предъ/pred are the prefixes in the Old Slavonic;
the letter щ (shch) is always derived from the letters к (k) or г (g) + т (t);
the letter ц (ts) is always derived from the letter к (k) when it stands between the letters и (i) and а (a);

Comment: Do you have a specific semantics in mind or just the sound? Given German *rechnen* "to calculate" from that root the semantics might fit, analoguously to *zählen* "to count",*erzählen* "to tell, recount*, En *to tell, count, recount* etc. That's what you expected, right? I don't know about the phonetics, though. I'd go as far as considering the prefix *er-* derived from the same root, comparing *to count up*, and the root glossed *upright*, though Ger *abzählen* would imply *ab* "down, away*, hence *to count down*. Now what about *rex* "king" and *op-ressor*, (*oppressor*, excuse the pun).

Comment: Regarding your question without getting at the heart of it, a) the author of the linked page may be inexperienced, usually glosses and bare stems are given for roots, but that argument doesn't count for the source, Dierksen. The relation may be older than PIE or newer. Go read Dierksen see if he makes an argument against *h3erg-.

Comment: Ooh and compare Ger. *Herrscher*. I know, laryngeals were lost, not becoming /h/ in any case, but you know, it fits, v. *herschen* "to rule, command". The speech of nobles doesn't necessarily have to participate with the bulk of cowheards. And a ruler can bring foreign words.

Comment: @vectory regarding "rex", e.g. the one who have a voice in; the one who command; one who may speak and all others must listen/obey (rhetor, speech origin)

Comment: @vectory Laryngeals were lost from every single IE language by the thirteenth century BCE when Hittite (which preserved `*h₂` in some environments) went extinct. It seems implausible that the ruling class would have kept saying the laryngeals for thirty-three hundred years without ever writing them down, and there's similarly nowhere they could have borrowed from that would retain the laryngeals. (And that's assuming `*h₃` would be interpreted as `/h/`, when its reconstruction is still uncertain…)

Comment: @MichaelStallone It's entirely plausible that `*h₃-rg-` would end up having a descendant meaning "speak"; compare Latin *rogō* "to ask" (from something like "to correct yourself", from the original meaning "right, straight"). But assuming the original PIE meaning "speak" makes it very hard to get to Latin meanings like *rectus* "in a straight line". It's a lot easier to take "right, straight" as the original and go from there.

Comment: @Draconis regarding "original": In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.

Comment: @MichaelStallone Sorry, but talking about etymology somewhat requires believing that words can be derived from other words. Citing the Bible isn't quantifiable evidence.

Comment: @Draconis there's no saying when the laryngeals were lost (or is there a glottochronological hypothesis?). I was think the word might have been borrowed after the Germanic branch lost it, but before the lending branch did. Another possibility may be an added h by analogy to *Herr*, so, thanks for being insistent.

Comment: @vectory An analogy to _Herr_ is my guess, though I sadly have no Germanic etymological dictionaries on hand. Might make a good question to ask here, though!

Comment: Regarding rect-, I noted "to count *up*". I mean, what's long, straight, and used to count length?

Comment: Previously I would correlate *just* "straight, set right", *just* "fair, justice*, *just* "right now, current", and the same with Ger. *recht, gerade, gerecht* (deeming those calques to a degree). I didn't forgot when commenting last. Now I find the idea of "current ruler" quite funny, or "news, current word".

Answer (score 5):

First, a note: it's often best in etymology to go back to the last form we can be reasonably sure of. As you mention, OCS *щ* (often written `/ť/` because linguists like the Latin alphabet better than the Cyrillic) basically always comes from Proto-Slavic `*kt`, which sometimes comes from earlier `*gt` by voicing assimilation. So we can reconstruct the Proto-Slavic form as something like `*rekti` or `*regti`.

There's some semantic difficulty in getting from "straight" to "to say", which isn't totally insurmountable: see Latin *rogō* "to ask" from the same PIE root. Similarly, there's some difficulty in dealing with the PIE "palatovelar" `*ǵ`, but Balto-Slavic never satemized fully, and there's plenty of precedent for `*ǵ` not satemizing.

So, it seems plausible that it *could* come from this root. But there's some other difficulty that's harder to get away from. First of all, there's no evidence of `*h₃r-ǵ-` ever acquiring a meaning of "speak" in Balto-Slavic languages. Instead it's acquired a meaning of "see", like in Latvian *redzēt* < **regt* or Lithuanian *regéti*. Second, there are a decent number of IE words looking vaguely like `*rekti`, in widely-spread languages which all have widely different descendants of `*h₃r-ǵ-`. And absolutely none of them show satemization, which is explainable for Slavic but a bit weird when it happens in all sorts of different satem languages.

So it seems easier to reconstruct a separate root for these, which doesn't have to deal with satemization. Vasmer suggests something like `*r-k-` plus a suffix.

Answer (score 0):

In Lithuanian language there are such words: rėkti, rėkia (to shout, is shouting), riksmas (a shout) and other synonyms, also there is Rikis (a king and a battle commander). The relatives of word Rikis in other PIE languages for example Rex (Latin), Rixs (Proto-Celtic), Reikis (Celtiberian) might have origin in loud speaking / shouting being related to ruling and making order.